# Compute $g'(x)$ without computing the integrals explicitly.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Compute $g’(x)$ without computing the integrals explicitly.$$g(x) = \int_{\arcsin x}^{\operatorname{arcsinh} x} (1+t^2)^{\frac32}\, dt$$

How can I solve this question? Please consider that I don't understand it.

Comment: Use differentiation under the integral sign.

Comment: Take F(x) = integral of f(x). What is F’(x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}g(x)&=\int_{\arcsin x}^0(1+t^2)^\frac32\,\mathrm dt+\int_0^{\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)}(1+t^2)^\frac32\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^{\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)}(1+t^2)^\frac32\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^{\arcsin(x)}(1+t^2)^\frac32\,\mathrm dt.\end{align}Now, apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the chain rule.

Comment: I got it, thanks very much but please tell me how do you insert these mathematical symbols, mine is just an image but yours look it's an inserted symbols from this website, How can I do that?

Comment: @MohamedMagdy Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: @MohamedMagdy. Click on 'edit' to see how the formulas a written.

Comment: @md2perpe I should have given that piece of advice.

Comment: Is it mean that I should integrate each of those and then differentiate them?

Comment: @MohamedMagdy No! Just use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculos and the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H(x)$ be the antiderivative of the integrand $h(x):=(1+x^2)^{3/2}$. Then

$$g(x)=H(\text{arsinh}(x))-H(\arcsin(x))$$

and by the chain rule,

$$g'(x)=h(\text{arsinh}(x))\,\text{arsinh}'(x)-h(\arcsin(x))\,\arcsin'(x).$$